# SQL/ MySQL: Multiple rows AND multiple columns into single result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table with 3 VARCHARs in 3 different columns:

```
         user    owner   initiatorUser
------------------------------------
row1     UserA,  UserC,  UserC
row2     UserB,  UserC,  UserA
```

Now I need every occurence in all rows and in all the 3 columns as distinct VARCHAR result set or, if not possible, as a CSV.

```
UserA
UserB  
UserC
```

I know that was discussed quite often here, but none of the solutions applies for me. I experimented with MYSQL's GROUP_CONCAT, but couldn't get a fitting result.

Thanks for any help !
Gerry

Comment: not as a  'single line' (row), but as a single column with the 3 rows. 

The solution below shows it. 


Anyway, thanks for caring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the expected result you can use `UNION`.

If the coma after the values isn't a typo use:

```
select replace(user,',','') as distinct_
from my_table
union
select replace(owner,',','')
from my_table
union
select initiatorUser
from my_table
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d4d8988f7ed2a7200bab1530a7a3dfa

If it is a typo use:

```
select user as distinct_
from my_table
union
select owner
from my_table
union
select initiatorUser
from my_table
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7eeab79bf33689965ea3cf35a2f98ca

Comment: Thank  you very much for your time and this solution  ! Works perfect. 
I wasn't even aware of the 'UNION' statement.

The coma was indeed a typo. Thanks for pointing out ! But that gave me the chance to take a deeper look at the 'replace' statement which I also did not know.